# Designing stream and subject names in NATS

Tags: c#, .net, nats.io

I have several exchange connectors that subscribe to 3rd party websocket streams and I then use Durable JetStream to publish that information and consumers are processing that data elsewhere.

The question is how do I name/design `stream` and `subject`? Stream per exchange `deribit`, `binance` and so on and subject e.g. `trades`, `candlesticks`, `aggregated-trade`. Tickers are per symbol, so I could publish to `tickers.btcusd`, `tickers.icpusd` and then use wildcards for the subscriber `tickers.*`.

The exchanges can be: binance, coinbase, kraken, deribit, okex, etc. Each one of these exchanges can publish data from the following streams:

- Aggregate Trade Streams
- Trade Streams
- Candlestick Streams
- User Trade Streams
- Symbol Ticker Stream
- Book Depth Streams

What do you suggest?